# Two closed lagrangians embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ can be shifted and perturbed to intersect at two points

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

In Polterovich paper ["The surgery of Lagrange manifolds"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01896378.pdf). It is stated in page 204 - in proof of Theorem 7a - the following,

> If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are two Lagrangian submaifolds of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, then after suitable linear shift and small perturbation we can assume $L_1$ and $L_2$ have exactly two intersection points.

I will be glad if some one help me see how such small perturbation is made so that we get exactly two points of intersections.